# Background service using too much memory

Tags: java, android, performance, websocket, socket.io

For a friend of mine who is deaf and blind i am trying to create application (for smartwatch and phone) which warns him when someone is ringing the doorbell. The smartwatch will vibrate and that way he knows someone is in front of the door.

In order to know if someone is ringing the doorbell i created a server which sends a message to the phone through sockets. The phone will listen for this in a service and then when it gets a message it will send the data through the data layer api to the smartwatch to vibrate.

Now i got the background service working, but it is using way to much memory. A few days later i saw a message on my phone which said the application was using way to much memory so it automatically shut down the app. My question is what is using alot of memory in my service? Is the socket io library i am using not ment to be used in the background?

(Also every few minutes the user disconnects from the server and reconnects, this keeps on going)

Here is the service i created:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Socket;
import io.socket.emitter.Emitter;
import nl.example.messenger.Messenger;

public class SocketIOService extends Service {

    private final static String mSocketUrl = "https://example.io/";
    private Socket mSocket;
    private Messenger mMessenger;
    private final LocalBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder{
       public SocketIOService getService(){
            return SocketIOService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
       return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        initializeSocket();
        addSocketHandlers();

        mMessenger = new Messenger(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        closeSocketSession();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void initializeSocket() {
        try{
            IO.Options options = new IO.Options();
            options.forceNew = true;
            mSocket = IO.socket(mSocketUrl, options);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Error", "Exception in socket creation");
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private void closeSocketSession(){
        mSocket.disconnect();
        mSocket.off();
    }

    private void addSocketHandlers(){

        mSocket.on("message", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                mMessenger.sendMessage("Socket: Got a new message.");
            }
        });

        mSocket.connect();
    }
}
```

Comment: There's not enough code here to make this determination. What you've provided is unlikely to cause such a severe memory leak. It is unlikely to be Socket.IO. See [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler) for instructions on how to profile memory.

Comment: Besides this there is only 1 activity which just starts te service. But i will take a look into the instructions!

Answer (score 0):

You need GC tool to locate memory leak position.